# Android - Display listview after pressing a button.

Tags: android, android-listview, onclick, android-sqlite, android-button

Not really sure where to start but here it goes:

I have an app that accepts a text entry with a push button. When the button is pushed, the value of the text entry gets saved to a variable and a couple of SQLite queries are run. One selects information from the database based upon the text entry and the other runs an insert on the database.

At the end of the queries, a listview should display below the button that shows the select query info.

It all works except when I enter another value and push the button, nothing happens and I have a Log call to tell if the button is pushed and that does not display either.

On button click event it is calling another activity that runs the query and listview, when I place a finish() on the called activity, it allows the insert query to run every time I click the button but does not display the listview.

Here is my orderEntry Activity:

```
public class orderEntry extends Activity  {

private EditText itemNumb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.orderentry);

    //final Intent searchItem = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DBListActivity.class);

    itemNumb = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUPC);
    Button enterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEnterItem);

    enterButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Intent searchItem = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DBListActivity.class);

            Intent searchItem = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),inputOrder.class);
            String itemNumberValue = itemNumb.getText().toString();
            searchItem.putExtra("itemnumval", itemNumberValue);

            Log.v("Button Pushed","Yes");

            startActivity(searchItem);

        }
    });

}

}
```

Here is my listview activity:

```
public class inputOrder extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private final String MY_DATABASE_NAME = "hdw";
ArrayList results = new ArrayList();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.itemlist);
    setContentView(R.layout.orderentry);


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String itemNumberValue = intent.getExtras().getString("itemnumval");

    SQLiteDatabase myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(MY_DATABASE_NAME, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE, null);
    try {

        String itemSel = "IMITNO";
        String itemDescInsert = "IMITD1";
        String itemDesc = "Test";

        Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery("Select * from items where IMITNO = '"+itemNumberValue+"'",  null );

            /* Check if our result was valid. */
        if (c != null) {

        c.moveToFirst(); // it's very important to do this action otherwise your Cursor object did not get work
            int itemNumCol = c.getColumnIndex("IMITNO");
            int itemDescCol = c.getColumnIndex("IMITD1");
             /* Check if at least one Result was returned. */
            if (c.isFirst()) {
                int i = 0;
                  /* Loop through all Results */
                do {
                    i++;
                    String itemNum = c.getString(itemNumCol);
                    itemDesc = c.getString(itemDescCol);
                    String itemDescColumName = c.getColumnName(itemDescCol);

                       /* Add current Entry to results. */
                    results.add("" + i + ": " + itemNum + " " + itemDesc + " " + itemDescColumName + ")");
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
        }

        String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO orders(itemnumber, desc) VALUES ('"+itemNumberValue+"', '"+itemDesc+"')";
        Log.v("Insert:",insertSQL);
        myDB.execSQL(insertSQL);

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
    } finally {
        if (myDB != null)
            myDB.close();
    }

    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.listlayout, results));

    finish();
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that `results` contains values? And are you saying that it works the first time but not after that or your `ListView` is never displayed?

Comment: When it runs the first time and I click on the button, everything works, data is inserted into database and listview displays data. When I enter another number and press the button, nothing happens.I have a log output to show when the button is pressed and log is not displayed on second press.

Comment: I noticed yesterday while debugging that without the finish() in my listview activity, the activity stays focused, when I hit the "back button" I can enter a new number and it shows. With finish() in the activity, it does go back to the calling activity but when I enter an item, it briefly shows details on the list but then goes away. How can I populate and display the list after the activity finishes?  How do I refresh the list view?

Comment: I'm confused on what you are doing. Why do you have `finish()` there? You are creating the `Activity` then finishing right away after it loads so of course it won't stay on...

Comment: I pulled the finish() out and the listview stays but how can I go back to the previous activity and keep the list view displayed?

Comment: You can't. You will recreate it when you come back to this `Activity`.